# What is the correct rails model? Using redundancy recommended?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, model, entity-relationship

In my rails application *Company* acts as the *user model*. A *company* can have many *customers* and many *employees* (carseller).

There is a many to many relation between a *carseller* and a *customer*.

There is the following problem: A lot of times i'd have to retrieve all the appointments made with the whole company. Since there is no company_id saved in the *appointment* model this can be quite painful.

Should i just include a foreign key to company in the appointments and have some form of redundancy or is there another easy and efficient way?

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base  
   has_many :customers
   has_many :carseller
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base  
   belongs_to :company

   has_many :appointments
   has_many :carsellers, :through => :appointments
end

class Carseller < ActiveRecord::Base   
   belongs_to :company

   has_many :appointments  
   has_many :customers, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :customer
   belongs_to :carseller
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use :

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :carseller
  has_one :company, :through => :carseller
end
```

Then you just have to do `appointment.company` to get it.

Comment: Thanks. But much more important is the other direction: Getting all appointments which belong to a certain company

Comment: Then, you do the same in the `Company` model like this : `has_many :carsellers` and `has_many :apppointments, :through => :carsellers`

Comment: That's the way i tried it. And then accessing it with company.appointments. But unfortunatly it doesn't work :-( (undefined method `appointments' for #<Company:0x000001027d19c0>)

Comment: Have you written `carsellers` instead of `carseller` like in the code above ?

Comment: Maybe Rails doesn't support it because there 2 many-to-many, I don't know. You can try using raw SQL in a helper method of Company ;)

Comment: @Ben let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2574/discussion-between-skydreamer-and-ben)

Comment: It worked now. FYI I had to not only add has_one :company, :through => :carseller to Appointment but also has_many :apppointments, :through => :carsellers to Carseller. So it just works with both. One of the to is not enough.